# Notification about authentication failure in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I need a notification for the client application about an authentication problem in Chrome browser (for IE we used `IHttpSecurity:: OnSecurityProblem` ).
I found an experimental API `chrome.experimental.ssl.onCertificateVerify` but it is not working. I get error `“chrome.experimental.ssl is undefined”`. I added the `“experimental”` permissions to the manifest and enabled the flags. So I assume that this interface is obsolete.
Is there a way to get the notification in Chrome?